# Error when installing Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server

When I install Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express on Windows 10, the following error appears:

> TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> ```
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.ParameterBuilder
> ```
>
> System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder.DefineParameter(Int32,
>   System.Reflection.ParameterAttributes, System.String)'..

[Error image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4je7d.png)
 Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I *believe* this is related to a version conflict with the prerequisite .Net Framework v3.5   I'd consider manually installing this via the "Windows Feature"

Comment: Thanks. But i installed .Net Framework v 3.5 and other versions.